# How to limit contract compatibility to specific ERC20 token?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, tokens

How would I go about making sure users of a DApp can only interact with the contract using a specific ERC20 token?

For example, say a user has Ethereum, Token 1, and Token 2 in their wallet. The DApp uses Token 2. How can I make it so if they send anything other than Token 2 to the DApp contract, they are refunded.

Answer (score 0):

You would essentially just be looking at the specific token contract that you want to interact with and make a call to the public function that lists the owners of tokens. All ERC20 tokens have a balance of function:

`function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint256);`

also all transfers are done from that same contract:

`function transfer(address to, uint256 value);`

as long as you are only interacting with the contract for the token that you want to use... you shouldn't have a problem.